# pthread fails to link without a call in main

Tags: c++

I've been attempting to use angelscript and I keep getting linker errors, however if I put a reference to pthread_exit(NULL) at the end of my main function it builds, links, and runs normally.

Here is the code in question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <angelscript.h>
#include <cassert>

// This is used for AngelScript error messages
void MessageCallback(const asSMessageInfo &msg)
{
    const char *type = "ERR ";
    if( msg.type == asMSGTYPE_WARNING )
    {
        type = "WARN";
    }
    else if( msg.type == asMSGTYPE_INFORMATION )
    {
        type = "INFO";
    }

    std::cout << msg.section << " (" << msg.row << ", " << msg.col << ") : " << type << " : " << msg.message << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    asIScriptEngine* engine = asCreateScriptEngine(ANGELSCRIPT_VERSION);

    int r = engine->SetMessageCallback(asFUNCTION(MessageCallback), 0, asCALL_CDECL);
    assert(r >= 0);

    std::cout << "Testing" << std::endl;

    engine->Release();
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the command line:

```
g++ -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -Wl,-O1 -o fib main.o   -langelscript -lpthread
```

any ideas?

Comment: I've narrowed it down to --as-needed, looks like I'm going to have to move from qmake.

Comment: Unrecognized command, I wonder if it's a GCC 4.9 bug, because if I include any other library that uses it, it compiles fine, case in point: SDL.